# Integrate Wordpress with golang

Tags: wordpress, go

I am developing a project in which the front-end part is done in wordpress and backend apis are in GO. I want to know whether they can be integrated.

Answer (score 5):

If your API is has a response that is understandable by third party then you can use any front-end technology with Go.

For example if your APIs are having response in JSON format, any front-end technology can use it, as long as it can understand JSON data.

**In short** you can use any back-end and front-end combination as long as they can understand each other.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but for cross domain requests I have to write proxy or is there any other way?

Comment: I'm just adding to the answer by @Mayank Patel. Here is a good tutorial on [How to import JSON into WordPress](https://codeable.io/how-to-import-json-into-wordpress/) with the [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) hook/action. I realise that you already resolved your dilemma by now. ;)